# Can't retrieve model with multiple words in flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How do I retrieve a model that has multiple words in flask-sqlalchemy? The following throws an error:

```
class Child(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    parent_one_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent_one.id'))

class ParentOne(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship('Child', backref='child.id', lazy='dynamic')
```

Looking at the DB, I see `parent_one` as the table name for respective model.

Attempt to get parent:

```
c = Child.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
print c.user.id    # Works
print c.parent_one.id    # Fails
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'Child' object has no attribute 'parent_one'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't have a `parent_one` attribute because you did nothing to cause one to be created.  Add a relationship from `Child` to `ParentOne` called `parent_one`, or do the reverse with a `backref` named `parent_one`.

```
# in Child
parent_one = relationship('ParentOne', backref='children')
# or in ParentOne
children = relationship(Child, backref='parent_one')
```

Also note that the relationship you did define has an invalid backref name (`child.id` is not a valid Python variable name).  You seem to have confused `backref` with `ForeignKey`.